# SQL Insert/Update table from query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm quite new to SQL and am looking for a bit of help with a procedure I'm trying to write in SQL Server 2005.

I'm trying to insert or update a table with the results of a query.

I've written the INSERT fine and it works as expected however if the record already exists I want to update instead of insert.

My current code is :

```
INSERT INTO testTable
    ( field1 ,
      field2 ,
      field3,
      field4,
      field5 ,
    )                                   
select 
    'A000001'
    table2.field2,
    GETDATE() , 
    GETDATE()  ,
    NULL , 
    NULL , 
    0  

from 
    table1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field1 
INNER JOIN 
    table3 ON table2.field1 = table3.field1 
INNER JOIN 
    table4 ON table3.field1 = table4.field1 
WHERE condition
```

I want to change this so that if `field2` from the select is already in `testTable` then it will update instead of insert. I'm not sure how to do this as I may be returning multiple records.

I've had a look at some other questions but none I've found answer the question (or I'm not sure how to change the answer for multiple records)

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: SQL Server 2008 introduced `MERGE`. Unfortunately, pre-2008 leaves only poor options that involve multiple statements (but should be findable by searching for sql server 2005 merge or sql server 2005 upsert)

Comment: I had looked at upserts but it would mean I'd need to do my from statement again and I wasn't sure if this was correct. If there are multiple records being returned will this cause issues?

Comment: You can store the result of the `select` in a temp table/table variable if the `select` part of the query is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT

```
INSERT INTO testTable
    ( field1 ,
      field2 ,
      field3,
      field4,
      field5 ,
    )                                   
select 
    'A000001'
    field2,
    GETDATE() , 
    GETDATE()  ,
    NULL , 
    NULL , 
    0  

from 
    table1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field1 
INNER JOIN 
    table3 ON table2.field1 = table3.field1 
INNER JOIN 
    table4 ON table3.field1 = table4.field1 
WHERE condition and not exists(select * from testable where table1.field2=testable.field2)
```

UPDATE

```
UPDATE test
SET
    test.field1='A000001'
    test.field3=GETDATE() , 
    test.field4=NULL , 
    test.field5=0  

from 
    testtable as test inner join table1 on test.field2=table1.field2
INNER JOIN 
    table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field1 
INNER JOIN 
    table3 ON table2.field1 = table3.field1 
INNER JOIN 
    table4 ON table3.field1 = table4.field1 
WHERE condition
```

Comment: sorry I should have made my question a bit more clear, I know how to write the update function, its just working out when to update and when to insert I'm struggling with.

Comment: The code I have written will take care of WHEN to INSERT and WHEN to UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

the best operation is to use merge.

```
;with blabla as (select 
    'A000001'
    field2,
    GETDATE() , 
    GETDATE()  ,
    NULL , 
    NULL , 
    0  

from 
    table1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field1 
INNER JOIN 
    table3 ON table2.field1 = table3.field1 
INNER JOIN 
    table4 ON table3.field1 = table4.field1 
)
merge into test as target
using (select * from blabla) as sources (columnlist...)
on field2 = field2
WHEN MATCHED and Source.Field2 <> Target.Field2 THEN
    UPDATE SET ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (..) VALUES (..)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN
DELETE;
```

Comment: From OPs question: "I'm trying to write in SQL Server 2005."

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2005 so this isn't an option I'm afraid